# Android mp4 videos doesn't play in Emulator as well as device

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, mp4

I want to stream mp4 videos from my Android phone in my Android app. The videos are stored in a server. All I have is their URL's. I tried the code below, but it didn't play my  videos (it worked fine with .3gp videos on both the emulator and the device) I'm using Galaxy Y hardware and the emulator is 4.2 version of Android. Please don't refer to me any links, I honestly did a lot of searching but all of it got in vain. I can't use `WebView`, I have to use `VideoView` in my app.
The code is:

```
private void playVideo() {

    try {

    final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}
```

Where path is initialized to a link:

`path = http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Android MediaPlayer is finicky about the video format and encoding. Doubly so when it is streaming instead of local playback. Try re-encoding your video with some software that has a preset "Android device profile" for encoding. Try playing the video that you have in the stock browser (outside of your app) if it doesn't work that way then there is little chance that you are going to get it to work on that device by changing your source code, you'll probably have to tweak the encoding of the video. Also in general I think it is better to avoid things like "Please don't refer to me any links"

Comment: Using the emulator is slow at most things especially if you are not using the x86 version. It is entirely expected that performance of the emulator isn't great.

Comment: @draksia I tested it on device too. But it was not playing there either.

Comment: @FoamyGuy What changes in source code you're talking about?

Comment: @AbdusSamiKhan what I am saying is that if your video doesn't play within the stock browser then you probably won't be able to make it play within your app (no matter what code you use). You'll have to re-encode the video and tweak the encoding settings.

Comment: It's playing fine in the stock browser.